# "Parallel reduction arrow": -//->

Tags: arrows, overlays

What's the best way to get a "parallel reduction arrow" (as in the one used to show confluence of the `$\lambda$`-calculus, if that means anything)

Concretely I want an arrow with a `//` crossing the middle of it. Using `||` could also be acceptable.

Right now I have:

```
\newcommand{\rpbeta}{\mkern-7mu\centernot{\mkern7mu\centernot\rbeta}}
```

where `\rbeta` is `$\longrightarrow_\beta$`.

Giving something kind of OK, but spacing seems to vary each time I use it.

Comment: What is `\rbeta`, please?

Comment: Ah, sorry, $\longrightarrow_\beta$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use my favourite `\mathcenterto{#1}{#2}` construct which allows you to center `#1` over `#2`. One additional `\mathclap` makes the right-side slash centered and the left-side one adjacent to it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\mathcenterto[2]{\mathclap{\phantom{#2}\mathclap{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand*\rpbeta{\mathrel{\mathcenterto{\mathclap{/}/}{\longrightarrow}}_\beta}

\begin{document}

\[
A \rpbeta B
_{A \rpbeta B
_{A \rpbeta B
_{A \rpbeta B
}}}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate the working of `\centernot`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rpgeneric}[1]{\mathpalette\rp@generic{#1}}
\newcommand{\rp@generic}[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \rlap{%
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1{\longrightarrow}$}%
      \kern.55\dimen@
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1=$}%
      \kern-.53\dimen@
      $\m@th#1\not$%
      \kern-.3\dimen@
      $\m@th#1\not$%
    }%
    {\longrightarrow_{#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rpbeta}{\rpgeneric{\beta}}

\begin{document}

$\rpbeta_{\rpbeta}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the mathtools package, I would use amsmath.txfonts with the following code (however the fonts could create some other problems elesewhere in the text...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,txfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\mathrlap{\longrightarrow}\varparallel$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to actually use it? Like in `$A\mathrlap{\longrightarrow}\varparallel B$`?

Comment: Yeah, spacing looks a bit bad on this one.

Comment: I really don't understand how can someone upvote this answer. It's plain wrong as the spacing is completely off. This is unusable.

Comment: Note also that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so in your case having `amsmath` is redundant.

Comment: Besides breaking the spacing, loading `txfonts` will change the appearance of the whole document. You wouldn't rebuild a house just for getting a new window, would you?